# I2C temperature sensor always NACKs

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, light-sensor

I am trying to communicate with a temperature sensor via I2C. To do this I use a Cortex M3 based microcontroller.

So I am trying to get the id of the module to be sure evrything starts well. But already get a NAK there:

[image: signal]

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong in my short piece of software?
As you see The 0x44 (which I need) gets transmitted. But My mc sends a NAK for some reason. Also when I try to print the data I receive it prints wrong data (mostly 0).

Does anybody know why?

```
void setupI2c()
{
     SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
     SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_I2C7);
     GPIOPinConfigure(0x00001002);
     GPIOPinConfigure(0x00001402);
     GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);
     GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);

}

void getModel()
{
int i=0;
int k;
int data[1]={0};

int g_ui32SysClock = SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_320), 40000000);

        I2CMasterInitExpClk( I2C7Master_Base, g_ui32SysClock, false);
        I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C7Master_Base, 0x29, false); //true = read


    I2CMasterControl(I2C7Master_Base, I2C_MASTER_CMD_SINGLE_SEND);
    I2CMasterDataPut(I2C7Master_Base, 0x80|0x12); // result register
    while(I2CMasterBusy(I2C7Master_Base));

    /******************************/
    /*for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {k++;}
*/
    /******************************/

    I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C7Master_Base, 0x29, true); //true = read
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {k--;}
    I2CMasterControl(I2C7Master_Base, I2C_MASTER_CMD_SINGLE_RECEIVE);
    data[0]=I2CMasterDataGet(I2C7Master_Base);
    while(I2CMasterBusy(I2C7Master_Base));


    UARTprintf(" model: %x\n", data[0]);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that correct? I think you're allowed/supposed to NAK the last byte of a transfer.

Comment: YYeah - just looked it up: A master-receiver must signal the end of the transfer to the slave transmitter. http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf If you don't want that behaviour, maybe you have your bus master block set up wrong?